# Conditional Expectation to a non integrable Random Variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Given the joint-probability 
$$f_{XY}=x*e^{-x*(y+1)}1_{[0,\infty)}(x)1_{[0,\infty)}(y)$$

I am asked to compute the conditional expectation E[Y|X]. However, as the density of $f_Y$ is just $f_Y=\int f_{XY} dx$ and 
$$f_Y=\frac{1}{(y+1)^2}.$$
One can easily check, that $E[Y]$ is infinite and not integrable. As the formula $E[Y|X]=\int Y\frac{f_{XY}}{f_X}dy$ requires $Y$ to be integrable, in other words $E[Y]$ is bounded, how can I justify the use of the formula I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formular still holds for non-negative, not necessarily integrable random variables.

To see this have a look at the proof of it… it's shown in three steps (usually)

1.) for simple random variables

2.) for non-negative ones

3.) for integrable ones

You use 1.) to proove 2.) and 2.) to proove third.
But for 2.) you don't need integrability of Y…

Comment: I think it destroys the Equality E[E[Y|X]]=E[Y] since the order of integral cannot be changed as the condition for Fubini doesn't satisfy.

Comment: I can't find nowhere the proof, could you give a hint of the proof?

Comment: But it doesnt… the conditional expectation can also be defined in the above way (simple,non-neg,integrable) so the Law of total expectation (the one you asked for) also holds for non-negative random variables although they can be infinite…

Comment: And for a general random variable?

Comment: There it also hold… if you want to proove it with using fubini check out that fubini also holds if the integrand is non-negative (check wikipedia for fubini, paragraph "Tonelli's theorem for non-negative functions")… and you are done.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the proof? We stated it as definition and I dont know really what is to proof

Answer (score 1):

you have a little mistake in your approach:
it should be
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y|X]= \int_{0}^\infty y \cdot \frac{f_{XY}(X,y)}{f_X(X)} \; dy.
$$
so the denominator inside the integral should be $f_X$ not $f_Y$. 
Note that i have written upper case $X$ and lower case $y$ and i did this on purpose: $X$ is a random variable and the outcome of the integral is a random variable as well. On the other hand $y$ is a real number.

The integral on the right hand side can easily be determined since the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is exponential with parameter $X$. Therefore
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y|X]= \frac{1}{X}.
$$

Comment: My question is, in order to use it, it required Y to be integralable, at least in our notes. However this condition is not satisfied, since Y is not integrable.

Comment: As OP states, this requires $E\lvert Y\rvert < \infty$.